# R: how to make sure R CMD BATCH does not produce non-ASCII characters?

Tags: r, encoding, r-package, rscript

In the `tests` section of a package, I typically run `R CMD BATCH` on some `xxx.R` files, which creates a `xxx.Rout.save`. Problem is that a failed `all.equal()` will create non-ASCII characters. This produces errors when running the `R CMD check` later on:

> Comparing ‘xxx.sim.Rout’ to ‘xxx.sim.Rout.save’
>
> -"Component \"short.run\": Mean relative difference: 0.2180449"
>
> -"Component 'short.run': Mean relative difference: 0.2180449"

This is due to the fact that `all.equal()` creates non-ASCII characters:

```
> tools::showNonASCII(all.equal(list(a=1), list(a=2)))
Component <e2><80><9c>a<e2><80><9d>: Mean relative difference: 1
```

And it seems `R CMD check` is running the `xxx.R` scripts with different options than the ones I used when running `R CMD BATCH`... Note that the R extension guide says:

> Please note that the comparison will be done in the end user’s locale,
>   so the target output files should be ASCII if at all possible.

But it is not clear how to make sure `R CMD BATCH` creates output in ASCII? I tried, `R CMD BATCH --encoding=ASCII` but it still creates a file with non-ASCII!?

```
cat("all.equal(list(a=1), list(a=2))", file ="xxx.R")
system("R CMD BATCH --encoding=ASCII xxx.R xxx.Rout")
tools::showNonASCIIfile("xxx.Rout")
file.remove(c("xxx.R", "xxx.Rout"))
```

gives indeed:

> "Component <80><9c>a<80><9d>: Mean relative difference: 1"

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the problem is to change the quotation marks in `all.equal()`. It turns out `all.equal()` uses [dQuote()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sQuote.html) for the quotes, either using fancy quotes or not, depending on `options()$useFancyQuotes`.

The easiest is to turn it off (which is off by default on Windows btw.):

```
options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)
```

Actually, using the default TRUE is just asking for trouble, see the documentation:

> **The choice of the appropriate quotation marks depends on both the
>   locale and the available character sets.** Older Unix/X11 fonts
>   displayed the grave accent (ASCII code 0x60) and the apostrophe (0x27)
>   in a way that they could also be used as matching open and close
>   single quotation marks. Using modern fonts, or non-Unix systems, these
>   characters no longer produce matching glyphs. Unicode provides left
>   and right single quotation mark characters (U+2018 and U+2019); if
>   Unicode markup cannot be assumed to be available, it seems good
>   practice to use the apostrophe as a non-directional single quotation
>   mark.